# Dynamically setting value of input from <template>

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to dynamically draw a range input, I have managed to get this far where on a button click a new range slider is created where the value will be constantly updated. What I now wish to do is to set the value of min, max, 
 and value from the draw_slider function.

The problem is I am unable to set the vars of input range slider, such as min, max, value.

I have attempted to get the child element of temp by

```
    var slider = [temp.children].filter(x=> x.className == "slider")[0];
    slider.value = 10;
```

```js
    function draw_slider()
    {
      var temp = document.querySelector('#slider_template');
      var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
      var menu_location = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_section")[0];
      menu_location.appendChild(clon);
    }
    function set_up_events()
    {
     document.querySelectorAll(".slidecontainer").forEach(function(element) {
        var slider = [...element.children].filter(x=> x.className == "slider")[0];
        var output = [...element.children].filter(x=> x.className == "slider-value")[0];
        slider.oninput = function() {
          output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
      });
    }
     
    function setup_menu()
    {
      draw_slider();
      set_up_events(); 
    }
```

```html
    <template id="slider_template">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input class="slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <br>  
        <span>Value:</span><span class="slider-value"></span>
        <br>  
    </div>
    </template>
    <div class="menu_section">
       
    </div>

    <button class = "button" onclick="setup_menu()">Copy text</button>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Forget it ! The code you put in a template will be stored in shadow dom. This is some kind of sandbox by design. You can not address this from normal dom. But you can cheat of them :) You can copy the template to the nomal DOM e.g. Document And then you can address all the things like normal. If you want to address this from the shadow dom, i am fairly sure you has to put your whole web page there. Shadow dom seems to be designed for components which should not be influenced. I try same. With custom html object you just can change text by so called slots. Not attributes etc.